# Vuetify dialog won't open in data table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This is my code for UI part:

```
<div>
   <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="showDialog(props.item)">
          <td>{{ props.item.company_name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
   </v-data-table>

   <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
   {{form}}
   </v-dialog>
</div>
```

this is my script code:

```
data(){
  return{
    dialog: false,
    form: {}
  }
},
methods: {
  showDialog(data){
    this.dialog = true
    this.form = data

  }
}
```

Now my problem is, v-dialog won't open even if the variable 'dialog' is equal to true. How can I show the dialog box?

Comment: honestly your code looks right, can you create a codepen?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```html
<tr>
 <td @click="showDialog(props.item)">{{ props.item.company_name }}</td>
</tr>
```

so the click will execute on every element 'company_name' of the table.

Also you can add a new column with a button to call the function

```html
<td>
    <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="showDialog(props.item)">
        <v-icon color="black">edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</td>
```